# How to set up an induction proof when there are multiple variables?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I want to prove by induction that
$n \choose k$
is always a natural number.  Assume: $0 \leq k \leq n$

First, I am unsure how to state the base case.  One idea is:

Let $n=1$, then $n \choose n$$=$$1 \choose 1$$=$$1$.  Since $1$ is a natural number, $n \choose n$ is a natural number.

Since the lowest value for $n$ is $0$, do I need to instead let $n=0$?  Also, what about $k$, do I need to explicitly let k equal something, should I have written let $n=k=1$ (or $0$)?

Then for the induction step, should I write: assume $n \choose k$ is a natural number, then go on to demonstrate that $n \choose k+1$ is a natural number, or do I have to increment both and show that $n+1 \choose k+1$ is a natural number?

I think we could ignore the details of the proof, I am just trying to understand how to frame the argument.

Comment: You can do an induction on, say, the sum $n+k$.  If $n+k=1$, the claim is clear.  And so on.  For instance, this works well if coupled with Pascal's rule, $\binom nk=\binom {n-1}k+\binom {n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain what the base case statement and inductive statement would be for your suggestion?  Sorry, I am new to writing induction proofs.

Comment: Let $F(n,k)=n+k$.  Then the base case is "the claim is true for $\binom nk$ if $F(n,k)=0$"  This is obvious (the base case usually is).  Now suppose you have proven the claim if $F(n,k)\leq m$.  Use Pascal to show that it is also true if $F(n,k)=m+1$.

Comment: Prove for n by using induction.
1 - Verify for $n = 0$. In this case $k = 0$ because $k \leq n$.
2 - Suppose it's true for $n$ and for any $k \leq n$ and prove it for $n + 1$. In this case you need to study the cases $k = n + 1$, $k = 0$ and $k \leq n$ (use the Pascal rule for the last case).

Comment: Prove for n by using induction.
1 - Verify for $n = 0$. In this case $k = 0$ because $k \leq n$.
2 - Suppose it's true for $n$ and for any $k \leq n$ and prove it for $n + 1$. In this case you need to study the cases $k = n + 1$, $k = 0$ and $k \leq n$ (use the Pascal rule for the last case).